# Is it possible to read the Cycle Count Register (DWT_CYCCNT) when executing at unprivileged?

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m

Is it possible to read the Cycle Count Register (DWT_CYCCNT) when executing at unprivileged?

```
#define DWT_CYCCNT  (*(volatile uint32_t*)(0xE0001004)) /**<  Cycle Count Register */
CycleCount = DWT_CYCCNT; /* Unprivileged read of the Cycle Count Register causes a Bus Fault. */
```

Related: [Measuring clock cycle count on cortex m7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355831/measuring-clock-cycle-count-on-cortex-m7)

Comment: I assume you want the cycle count register as a hires timestamp. `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` will do that on most arm arches. The register _can_ be made accessible to userspace with some kernel help. `clock_gettime` does that. The kernel (using the `VDSO` mechanism) will inject the code directly into the app (i.e. _no_ syscall required). If you write a program that calls `clock_gettime`, you can then disassemble it with `gdb` to see what it's doing. I've had to do all that before and I've found that using `clock_gettime` is _better_ than direct access to the register in most cases.

Comment: Thank you Craig; unfortunately I am not using Linux but have a bare metal application utilising unprivileged to lock down application

Comment: No, you cannot. I have run into this problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Debug registers are located in special reserved address space

> The architecture reserves address space 0xE0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF for system-level use. ARM reserves the
> first 1MB of this system address space, 0xE0000000 to 0xE00FFFFF, as the Private Peripheral Bus (PPB)

Register in question specifically

> Data Watchpoint and Trace (DWT) block 0xE0001000-0xE0001FFF

Section "**C1.2.1 General rules applying to debug register access**" explicitly state that DWT memory, as a rule of thumb, is **privilege access only**:

> The Private Peripheral Bus (PPB), address range 0xE0000000 to
> 0xE0100000, supports the following general rules:
>
> - The region is defined as Strongly-ordered memory
> - Registers are always accessed little-endian
> - Debug registers can only be accessed as a word access
> - A reserved register or bit field has the value UNK/SBZP
>
> **Unprivileged access to the PPB causes BusFault** errors unless otherwise stated.

Retrieved from "ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual" (ARM DDI 0403D)