# Why is this improved sieve slower with pypy?

Tags: python, performance, pypy

```
def sieve(n):
    nums = [0] * n
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if nums[i] == 0:
            for j in range(i*i, n, i):
                nums[j] = 1

    return [i for i in range(2, n) if nums[i] == 0]

def sieve_var(n):
    nums = [0] * n
    for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if nums[i] == 0:
            for j in range(i*i, n, i):
                nums[j] = 1

    return [2] + [i for i in range(3, n, 2) if nums[i] == 0]
```

On my machine, `sieve(10**8)` takes 2.28 s while `sieve_var(10**8)` takes 2.67 s. I don't think pypy's warmup time is the culprit here, so why isn't `sieve_var`, which iterates over less, faster? In standard python 3.3 `sieve_var` is faster as expected. Using pypy 4.0.1 32bit on Windows 8.1.

**Edit:** As a test, I added `count = 0` at the start of the function and `count += 1` inside the inner loop (where `nums[j] = 1` is). `sieve(10**8)` counts 242570202 while `sieve_var(10**8)` counts 192570204. So although the count isn't halved for `sieve_var`, it is doing less "work".

For fun, here is a version with slice indexing:

```
def sieve_slice(n):
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]
```

With python 3.6, `sieve_slice` runs about 4x faster than `sieve`, but with pypy3 7.3.0, `sieve` runs about 2x faster than `sieve_slice`.

Comment: @user2357112 if it's wrong then why does `sieve(10**8) == sieve_var(10**8)`?

Comment: How did you time this?

Comment: @user2357112 basically `t = time.clock(); print(len(sieve(10**8))); print(time.clock()-t)`

Comment: Did you time the two calls in the same process?

Comment: @user2357112 not sure what you mean but I ran both as separate programs

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. I get around 6.6s for `len(sieve(2*10**8))` and 7s for `len(sieve_var(2*10**8))`. I am using pypy 5.7.1 on  64 bit Windows.

Comment: more brainstorming ideas: when compiled by pypi, the `range` generator may use single `INC` instruction for the increment of 1, but not for 2... or processors may be able to predict the next value of `i` in the simpler situation and correctly guess the branches...

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why it's slightly slower on Windows.  On Linux the speed is the same.  However, I can answer why we get *mostly* the same speed.  The answer would be the same if the program was written in C, and the answer is purely at the level of the processor.  This program is bound on memory I/O accessing the list, which is 400 or 800MB in size.  In the second version, you're basically avoiding one extra `if nums[i] == 0` check.  This extra check costs nothing, though, because the CPU just fetched `nums[i - 1]` in its caches during the previous iteration and will need `nums[i + 1]` during the next iteration.  The CPU is waiting for the memory anyway.

To verify what I'm saying, try to make the `nums` array more compact.  I tried to access it with `nums[i // 2]`, assuming that `i` is always odd, and the result was twice faster.  You can probably win even more by not using a Python list (stored as an array of 32-bit integers on a 32-bit PyPy), but instead an array of bits (but it's much more code because there is no standard built-in array of bits).

Comment: The number of iterations of the inner loop is much smaller in the sieve_var case. Try this code: https://bpaste.net/show/bfbd7e66bdcb

Comment: One extra check? Isn't the second version doing half as many checks?

Comment: Yes, the second version is in theory doing half as many checks.  My point is that it's completely irrelevant because these checks are all in the cache and the benchmark is memory-bound.  I'm told it becomes 7 times faster (on 64-bit linux) by using a bytearray instead---and, surprize, that's almost the reduction of memory.

Comment: I don't think it is the correct explanation – I have changed this code to use `bytearray`; now on my home server (Linux) `sieve` and `sieve_var` take 55 and 39s respectively using python3, but 5.29 and 5.53 usiny pypy. So, sieve_var is still slower under pypy.

Comment: Why is it the same speed in pypy but not in python?

Comment: @qwr if you run pypy without jit-compiler (`pypy --jit off`) you will see that `sieve_var` is faster than `sieve`. I guess it is overhead from the intepreter, which makes the difference.

Comment: @ead and if you compare `sieve_var` with and without JIT, which one is faster? if it's faster with JIT, I wouldn't call it "overhead", just that the less sophisticated version of the code was easier to optimize

Answer (score 4):

TL,DR;

As a C-program this would be a memory bound algorithm. However, even jit-compiled pypy-code has considerably more overhead and the operations are no longer "for free". Surprisingly (or maybe not), rhese two `sieve` versions have different jit-code, it is probably just bad luck that the second version results in a slower code.

---

If it would be C,  @Armin's answer would be the right one. It is well known, that for modern computers/caches and memory-bound code it does not matter if we jump over an integer - nevertheless all values must be fetched from memory and this is a bottle-neck. See [this article](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/) for a great explanation.

Yet my experiments show that the non-optimized version (`sieve`) is slightly faster than the optimized version (`sieve_var`). Timings also shown, that the last line of `sieve` i.e. `[i for i in range(2, n) if nums[i] == 0]` is executed faster than the line of `sieve_var` - `return [2] + [i for i in range(3, n, 2) if nums[i] == 0]`.

On my machine it was`0.45` seconds vs. `0.65` seconds for `10^8` elements. These numbers may vary from machine to machine, so it is quite possible that somebody with faster CPU and slower memory would not see any difference at all. If it could be explained in terms of "memory dominates all", then we should be able to see, that the slower version has more cache misses as the faster version.

However, by running `valgrind --tool=cachegrind pypy sieveXXX.py` we can see, that there is almost no difference in number of cache misses, at least nothing that would explain the observable difference.

Let's consider a slightly simpler version, which exhibits exactly the same behavior - we don't save the primes, but just count them:

```
def sieve(n):
    ...
    res=0
    for i in range(2, n): 
          if nums[i] == 0:
              res+=1
    return res

def sieve_var(n):
    ...
    res=1
    for i in range(3, n,2): 
          if nums[i] == 0:
              res+=1
    return res
```

The first version is still faster: `0.35` sec. vs. `0.45` sec (to make sure the time difference is no fluke and not due to some jit-warmup, I put the last part of the code into a for-loop and got always the same timings).

Before going further, let's take a look at a C-implementation and its assembly

```
long long int sum(long long int *a, int n){
    long long int res=0;
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
       if(a[i]==0)
          res++;
    return res;
}
```

compiled with [gcc and `-Os` we get](https://godbolt.org/g/i8zKHd):

```
        movl    $2, %edx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.L4:
        cmpl    %edx, %esi
        jle     .L1
        cmpq    $0, (%rdi,%rdx,8)
        jne     .L3
        incq    %rax
.L3:
        incq    %rdx
        jmp     .L4
.L1:
        ret
```

Pretty small and straight forward and takes only `0.08` seconds on my machine. My memory can go as fast as 10 GB/s and there are `8*10^8` bytes - so the whole time was basically needed to get the data.

But from this we also see, that the pypy-version has about `0.25` seconds overhead compared to the C-code. Where does it come from? By utilizing the [vmprof-module](https://vmprof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) we can see the jit-code and:

1. for one iteration of the loop, there are many more operations than in the C-version
2. the versions for `sieve` and `sieve_par` are very different. We can [use debugger to count the number of instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628002/counting-machine-instructions-using-gdb) of an iteration: `24` for `sieve`  and `76`-operations for `sieve_var` which handles only every second element, so the relation is actually  `24:38`.

It is hard to tell, why jit-code is so different for both versions without debugging pypy. Probably it is just bad luck, that the `sieve_par` is slower.

Comment: Do you think the program is limited by list I/O speed?

Comment: Your answer is purely speculative.  If you're describing PyPy then it is wrong, sorry.

Comment: @ArminRigo You are right, it just a try to explain the experimental findings, because they can not be explained only in terms of memory band-width+caching. I'm very thankful to everybody who would correct my misunderstandings!

Comment: In this kind of boring example, PyPy implements the list as an array of (machine-sized) integers, and unboxes all integers.  That means that PyPy's JIT produces code close to what C would, and the difference is mostly missing low-level optimizations at which gcc is better.  Maybe someone should first try to write actual C code, to check if we *do* get different behaviour; that sounds like something that should be done before assuming we'll get a difference and guessing why.

Comment: I don't know which answer can be marked as "correct" but I'm giving you the bounty for the experimental effort to determine pypy vs C differences.

Comment: @qwr I guess both answers didn't answer your question in full.

Comment: I was kinda hoping someone who really knew the inner workings of pypy could give a authoritative answer, but it's more a curiosity to me than something actually serious, so I'm fine with the answers.

Comment: @ArminRigo Sorry to bother you again. I did some more digging and now it looks like the difference is due to a more efficient jit-code of the first version. Does it sound right? What could be the reason these differences? If compiled with C, the assembly of both version would not differ much...