# The program counts the number of clock STM32L152RCTx

Tags: timer, counter, clock, stm32

I have written code for ARM. Now I want to check the number of CPU clock counts code. How can this be done?

Comment: Duplicate - [Cycle counter on ARM Cortex M4 (or M3)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530593/cycle-counter-on-arm-cortex-m4-or-m3)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the assembler code that your compiler generated (e.g. objdump). With the assembler code it is possible to get the cycle count that your program takes to execute. You can also run your program in an ARM simulator/emulator to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

Your development environment most likely allows to see the number of clocks from program start to breakpoint in debug mode, if not you can use SysTick as a counter, considering its clock frequency (can be found in clock tree).