# Benchmarks on baremetal systems

Tags: arm, benchmarking, cortex-m, bare-metal, thumb

I am using the LPC43xx series, which has cortex-m4/m0. This is a bare-metal system. I am new to bare metal programming and I want to make small benchmark programs for performance evaluation. This is a non-cache system. How can I do this ? or Should I try profiling.

Comment: not having a cache greatly improves the quality of your results.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer. My system does not have a cache :)  Using Dhrystone , I am not sure how that code works, only on one core or both. what other  type of parameters can be implemented: I wish for memory bandwitdh,Memory Latency , cpu performance or so .Can all this be measured using threads?Is it possible to implement RTOS and work with  Pthreads. As bare-metal does-not go with threads.

Comment: thank you so much for the support,I guess including RTOS may reduce the performance of the system.

Comment: yep, that is true.. to me itseems like,it is like benchmarking two single cores which lies inside same chip! that is why i wanted to know if there are any methods for dual working

Answer (score 1):

As I know there are three ways to measure code execution time in your case:

- timers (init timer on frequency which you want, read timer value before and after code execution)
- gpio (or similar thing) set it to 1 before and to 0 after your code execution,
  use oscillograph to measure time
- performance counter embedded into CPU, in your case I think this one relevant:
  [Cycle counter on ARM Cortex M4 (or M3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530593/cycle-counter-on-arm-cortex-m4-or-m3)

Comment: is it possible to use these when both cores are performing the task ?

Comment: @Kael timer and gpio should work for both core case, about cpu counters you should carefully read cpu documentation.

Comment: @PeterJ I used all of them, and I suppose you missed the whole point. It is not for profiling (finding hot spot), it is for benchmarking of small algorithms. Like bubble sort vs quick sort.

Comment: @PeterJ You really not understand that algorithm that win go to software for this embedded system?

Comment: @fghj I have already agreed with you that I do not understand, have no clue ............. <- you can add more here .

Comment: so the approach which I can visualize is using all its different types of components